# iOS Binary Localizations

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, ios6, app-store-connect

Recently I have updated my iOS application by introducing Spanish and German translations. After uploading the binary to iTunes Connect, on Binary Details page it displays:

```
Localizations: ( "ca", "cs", "da", "de", "en", "es", "fi", "fr", "he", "hu", "it", "ja", "ko", "nb", "nl", "pl", "pt", "ru", "sk", "sv", "zh-Hans", "zh-Hant" )
```

Instead of just:

```
Localizations: ( "en", "es", "de" )
```

I want only English, Spanish, and German to be displayed as avaliable languages in iTunes after the update is approved. Is the current situation normal or I have to change something?

**Note:** The localizations are added by following the standard practice: en.lproj, es.lproj, and de.lproj folder with the appropriate Localization.string files. Everything works in iPhone Simulator and on test device.

Comment: This happened to me once. Are you using any libraries that might include localizations in them?

Comment: Yes, I am :) Thank you very much! I will remove the unneeded localizations.

Comment: I removed the unneeded localizations from the third party library and the problem is solved now. Thank you again!

Comment: I've posted as an answer, feel free to select my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third party libraries tend to stick their own localizations into your binary. Check that you're not using third party libraries and if you are, check their resources. You might need to clear out those extra localizations from there.